# multiple record form edit and submit synchronize

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Is there a possible way to make mutiple recordForm's mode and submit in sync?
I create a component which contains several recordForm component, and these recordForm contains some fields of a same sObject. In result, when I click the pencil on the right of the field, the recordForm's mode becomes edit and I could make a edit and submit it. Is there a way that I click a pencil, and all the recordForm becomes editable, when I click Save, all the recordForm validate the inputs and submit?

Code:

```
<lightning:accordionSection name="A" >
            <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm" objectApiName="T_ORDER__c" recordId="a1D0p000000JQsrEAG" fields="{!v.fields_basic}" columns="2" mode="{!v.recordFormMode}" isCollapsible="true"/>
            </lightning:accordionSection>
            <lightning:accordionSection name="B" >
                <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm2" objectApiName="T_ORDER__c" recordId="a1D0p000000JQsrEAG" fields="{!v.fields_service}" columns="2" mode="{!v.recordFormMode}" isCollapsible="true"/>
            </lightning:accordionSection>
            <lightning:accordionSection name="C" >
                <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm3" objectApiName="T_ORDER__c" recordId="a1D0p000000JQsrEAG" fields="{!v.fields_secret}" columns="2" mode="{!v.recordFormMode}" isCollapsible="true"/>
            </lightning:accordionSection>
            <lightning:accordionSection name="D" >
                <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm4" objectApiName="T_ORDER__c" recordId="a1D0p000000JQsrEAG" fields="{!v.fields_sales}" columns="2" mode="{!v.recordFormMode}" isCollapsible="true"/>
            </lightning:accordionSection>
```

Comment: dont think you can use standard edit button on field,but you can always use a separate button for this functionality

Comment: though you can save all using standard button